# Push viewcontroller which is an instance variable, dealloc method won't be called when pop it

Tags: ios, objective-c, dealloc

I have an AViewController, if I create BViewController as an instance variable like this

```
@interface AViewController ()
{
    BViewController *bVC;
}
@end
```

then push

```
- (void)push {
    bVC = [[BViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bVC animated:YES];
}
```

Dealloc method won't be called when BViewController pop.

Both viewcontrollers are almost empty, I mean there are no NSTimers, blocks or network requests.
I guess a strong reference cycle exists in AViewController, but can't figure out the cycle.

So, can anyone help me about this, thanks!

Comment: So, question, Ning, how did you test the dealloc, did you NSLog to check it to see if it was not being called, I'm just wondering because it seems very strange that it wouldn't be called.

Comment: Ning, I just tried this out on one of my apps that's close to production, and POPing the viewcontroller doesn't call dealloc, I've never paid attention to this before, but that's sort of odd. I also changed it to an IVAR like you have yours, and I'm getting the same behaviour.

Comment: The view controller is not being deallocate because there is still a reference to it. As long as `bVC` has a strong reference, it can't be deallocated.

Comment: yep, rmaddy, you are right, i just declared it again in the method only and dealloc is called,

Comment: @rmaddy what are the implications of having this as an IVAR vs otherwise? it's actually calling dealloc when the PUSH occurs after pushing and popping one time, totally backwards

Comment: here's an SO on this, Ning, not sure if this will help but it's giving me what I needed :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093136/who-calls-the-dealloc-method-and-when-in-objective-c?rq=1  I came to c languages after retain release was a deal with ios so , this so answer explains some good stuff

Comment: @Larcerax As you say, I write `NSLog(@"========= %@ dealloc", NSStringFromClass(self.class))` in dealloc method in BaseViewController. So I can clearly see if a viewcontroller is dealloc as it should be :）

Comment: yep, you are right, Ning, that's perfect, you should read rmaddy's answer, this is all good stuff, Im glad you asked this question, I will now be using IVARs a lot less

Comment: You can try to make a weak reference: __weak BViewController *bVC;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic memory management 101.

An object is deallocated only after there are no more strong references to the object.

Your ivar `bVC` has a strong reference to the view controller. Pushing it adds another. Then you pop it and it's back to just the one strong reference by `bVC`. So it doesn't get deallocated.

You can either avoid the ivar or set it to `nil` at some point so the view controller can be deallocated.

Comment: this is great, simple answer, simple concept, completely going chagne how much I'm using ivars. thanks!

Comment: i would rmaddy, but Ning asked this one, I upvoted you and the question, this is the first time in a long time that I've learned something that going to change the way I develop.

Comment: "Pushing it adds another" does this mean navigationcontroller will hold a strong reference to viewcontrollers in its stack?

Comment: Yes, the nav controller will retain its view controllers.

Comment: @rmaddy but  dealloc got when we again push the same viewcontroller in case of ivar.

Comment: Thank you. You have eliminated my mistake about strong references in ARC :）